# answers Finding duplicate values in mongodb array of objects

Tags: mongodb

find count values of question_paper_id

```js
[{
    "_id" : ("59b674d141b47e5401897d31"),
    "question_paper" : [ 
        {
            "question_paper_id" : "1001"
            
        }, 
        {
            "question_paper_id" : "1002"
            
        }, 
        {
            "question_paper_id" : "1001"
            
        },
        {
            "question_paper_id" : "1003",
        }   
    ],
    "pcode" : "120",
    
},
{
    "_id" : ("59b674d141b47e5401897d31"),
    "question_paper" : [ 
        {
            "question_paper_id" : "1001"
            
        }, 
        {
            "question_paper_id" : "1002"
            
        }, 
        {
            "question_paper_id" : "1001"
            
        },
        {
            "question_paper_id" : "1003",
        }   
    ],
    "pcode" : "123",
    
}]
```

etc...  1lak

Comment: if you can add the expected output, what you want the query to return?

Comment: o/p  question_paper_id:1001 count 1,  question_paper_id:1002 count 3,

Comment: why 1002 has countr3? and 1001 has count 1? i see 4 1001, and 2 1002

Comment: just an sample output given as per above  info  1001 count is 4. 1003 count 3,1002  count 1

Comment: its an exam paper type its REPATED, i m new to mongodb

Comment: {
    "_id": "106644",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "106940",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "268975",
    "count": 3
  },

Comment: {
    $group: 
    {_id : { question_paper_id : '$question_paper.question_paper_id'}, 
    
    total:{$sum :1}}
    
    
}